# Requisitos são achados ou criados?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, requisitos

Fala-se em Levantamento de Requisitos ou Elicitação de Requisitos (fazer aparecer). Também Coleta de Requisitos.

É uma tarefa de investigação, esclarecimento e formalização.

Não está claro para mim se requisitos são achados (existem previamente e são trazidos à luz) ou criados (não existem e passam a existir).

Qual dos dois é mais certo dizer?

Comment: Não sei, it's complicated. Dá pra ter uma discussão filosófica sobre isso e talvez existam os 2, e provavelmente não importa, interessa ter eles bem definidos antes de fazer algo.

Comment: O fato deles serem iterativos (descobertos aos poucos) também não ajuda a esclarecer, né? Tá certo.

Comment: Me parece que não tem certo. Vai "da ocasião".

Comment: Ou eles já existem ou não existem, acho que não pode ser os dois. :) ou o nosso entendimento sobre os requisitos que passa a existir?

Comment: Requisitos simplesmente "são" (cadê o @OnoSendai)?

Comment: "Eu quero que a busca seja igual a do Google". Isso foi um requisito criado né? "Eu testei, pensei um pouco e acho melhor que o PDF saia em Courier" foi uma descoberta, uma criação, ou ambos? Vi que uma nao era boa, mas criei uma que acho que me atende.

Comment: É, tem razão. Podem ser os dois.

Comment: Já votaram como baseada em opinião, mas eu tb acho meio ampla, até pq a definição "oficial" de requisito no contexto da pergunta ja é uma incógnita.

Comment: Eu que votei. Não sabia que a definição de requisito era uma incógnita.

Comment: Só aqui já são 3, e sem aplicar num ramo específico :D https://dicionario.priberam.org/requisito

Comment: Mas e requisito de software? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements

Comment: O da Wikipedia? Sao 5 referencias. Outras fontes podem usar outras referencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podem ser achados ou criados. É uma questão de interpretação de texto.

Os requisitos formalizados é claro que são criados, mas eles devem ocorrer em cima de um problema real existente. Então podemos dizer que eles são achados. Ou seja, a formalização ocorre em cima de algo que já existe, portanto achado.

Um dos grandes problemas do levantamento de requisitos é que nem sempre você os acha de forma adequada, aí a criação (formalização) acaba sendo errada, e a implementação obviamente também será.

O requisito em si sempre existe, se não existir não é um requisito. A formalização é criada, mas formalização não é o requisito.

Existem casos em que os requisitos podem ser definidos pelo analista e não pela observação dos processos que ele faz. Mas ainda são requisitos existentes. Ou são inventados, o que leva a dizer que serão implementações não requisitadas. O analista quiz fazer gracinha.

Mesmo que não seja um requisito de uma entidade específica o analista pode ver que há uma demanda geral e real para ter algo no sistema. Softwares de prateleira são feitos muito assim.

[Mais informações](https://pt.quora.com/O-que-%C3%A9-levantamento-de-requisitos-na-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/answer/Antonio-Maniero).

Answer (score 1):

Requisitos são criados porque eles não são leis da natureza para serem descobertos ou revelados e podem variar de acordo com a interpretação humana.

Answer (score -2):

Acho que o melhor termo a ser usado é que "Requisitos são levantados". Pois como fazem parte do mundo real eles meio que já existem, só são "trazidos à luz" ou algo parecido.